# The topology on $\mathbb Z_+$ given by $\emptyset, \mathbb Z_+$, and all sets of the form $\{n, n+1, n+2, ...\}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be the topology on $\mathbb Z_+$ given by $\emptyset, \mathbb Z_+$, and all sets of the form $\{n, n+1, n+2, ...\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z_+$. Give the limit points of $A = \{4, 13, 28, 37\}$. Find the closure of $A$. If $B$ is any infinite subset, show that $B^* =\mathbb Z_+$. ($B^*$ means the limit points of B).

Ok so I can determine (I think) that the set A literally goes to infinity after plugging in each value.

Comment: What work have you done on this so far?

Comment: None. I just have trouble figuring out how to start it. I mean it seems pretty straight forward but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to write and what to begin with.

Comment: You are unlikely to receive help unless you put *some* effort into the question. Put whatever you can. For formatting, take a look at the [Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "Give the limit points of $A = \{4, 13, 28, 37\}$." A good place to start here is by recalling the definition of a limit point.

Comment: And please do not _ever_ use phi to refer to $\emptyset$.

Comment: Haha sorry Benjamin. Ok I edited my post to show what work I had done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Set $O_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,\dots\}$ for simplicity.

Then $m$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if *every* open set containing $m$ intersects $A$ in a point different from $m$. If $m\ge37$, the open set $O_m$ doesn't intersect $A$ except in $m$ when $m=37$, so $m$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Note that $m\in O_n$ just means $n\le m$.

If $m<37$, then $37\in O_k\cap A$, for all $k\le m$. Thus every number less than $37$ is a limit point. The closure of $A$ is $A\cup A^*$, so…

Now, assume $C$ is a set such that some $m$ is not a limit point of $C$. Can $C$ be infinite?